# How can I create a program that works on all devices?

Tags: cross-platform

I am a beginner and I want to develop a software/application that works on all devices (computer, Android, Nokia, Blackberry). I want the application to be connected to a website or to be connected to the system software that will be created so that whenever the website or the system software is updated with information/news it appears on all the application. How can I go about this?

Comment: Do you actually mean *the same executable program*?

Comment: This sounds quite broad to me, it would help if you could narrow it down a little bit. Consider mentioning what kind of application you have in mind. What are the data source, how is the data being processed, accessed, stored etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can't at all.

The main advantage of *Web Apps* is that they **DON'T** depend on Operating System as they use only the browser. In that case, it is cross-platform because it would run in all systems through the browser.

If you mean an *executable* file, you can't. You have to prepare the *source code* in an generical way and then develop it with the specificities (*does this word exists in english?*) of the system.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not some PRO, but I think it's not possible at all. Not every device runs the same OS and I'm not sure If there's some option or function like "if" that says "if device is running this OS, install these files, if it's not, install these..". 
But If you'd like to do this program on web (like every component of the program is on your web server) it can be done :)

Comment: Okay thanks.
what am actually saying is that I want to have an application named "daily news" and there will be a version for blackberry OS, Android OS, window OS and Nokia OS. Am not saying I want to run the .exe (window OS ) application on other OS but to create same app for OS in .jar, .apk, .cod,  etc. I also want this app to be able to fetch information/news from my website everytime the website is updated.
I really need help on this.
Thanks

Comment: There is possibility when you just create an app in (as you said) .jar, .apk, .cod, etc. like app for every OS.. and when I'm reading it, It would be better to make it easier: Make the app just redirecting to your website's files that are needed and make there and GUI and all the other services, etc. will be on web. You won't have any problems with compatibility and It will be easier to program the actual app for mobile.